# Animation Delay will not add

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a delay on my flip animation by adding the animation-delay property like so:

```
.flip-container:hover .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

This is not working for me in the slightest however. Is there a better method?

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/CookieFresh89/pen/sfgiL?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using transitions not animations

Try using `transition-delay` instead of `animation-delay`.

Comment: Thank you (: Didn't even know there was a difference.

Comment: @TonyStark They are similar, think of animations as a group of one or more transitions, with animation you have to define the animation keyframes but this way you can transition multiple properties and have more control over each transition step. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: Thanks for the great reference!